# What do the numbers on sole of heel mean on my Brasher boots?

Tags: boots

I have had a pair of Brasher Air 8's for some years now, but will get rid of them as they feel heavy now that I am getting older and more arthritic. However, whilst they are size UK 7, on each heel (on sole) they have the number 5. Any idea what that means, please?

Comment: Could we see a photo?

Comment: Berghaus who now work with Brasher said they can identify this only by a photo... Can you please add one?